# Thread class empty constructor

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering what's the reasoning of the existance of an empty constructor on Thread class.

Since you cant give it a Runnable when it's created, creating a Thread like this:

```
Thread t=new Thread();
```

Is completely useless.

Can you think of a reason why there is not an option of adding a runnable to a thread AFTER CREATION?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
         System.out.println("Well you can change the run method.");
    }

}
```

but yes that's not what I'd consider good practice.

Comment: @Ofek Because that doesn't add anything useful, while making the API more complex - that's something API designers generally try to avoid whenever possible. In general you shouldn't ask "Why is something **not** in the API" but instead "Why should something be in the API?". Slightly offtopic: The original designers imho did make some mistake with the Thread API though: Making `run` protected would've avoided some problems without any real downside. Removing the no args constructor would imho be advantageous too.

Answer (score 8):

You can override the `Thread` class, too. Your own implementation could then do something sensible in the `run()` method without the need for a `Runnable`.

Comment: Why then it is not `protected`? But i agree, it seems only for overriding purposes.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread` class can be subclassed, and it's `run()` overriden. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).